# Load docx file from assets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a terms and conditions .docx document,  If you have a crypto.com account you see in the terms and conditions they essentially just load a docx document out of somewhere. I'd like to load mine from my assets using [file_reader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_filereader) but it takes the full path of the file, not the relative assets file.

I guess the real question is where can I store this file, so when I compile it, I can then somehow figure out the path of the file, and then feed it to the `FileReaderView`.

Comment: If the file is present while compiling, you can simply copy the data from the file into code or load a text file. A docx file will need external libraries and it'll be heavy load.

Comment: @WilfredAlmeida could you provide some insights on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Copy all text and put it in a string variable. Use ```""" """```. These tripe quotes will will take text with proper formatting. Now you can use the string variable in your widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file). It may solve your problem, they use a relative path.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I have tried that plugin and it doesn't open the path if its not full

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to add code. It is as another answer, down below.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Future<File> openFileFromAsset() async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    File tempFile = File('${tempDir.path}/set_any_name.docx');
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load('assets/en/legal_notes.docx');
    await tempFile.writeAsBytes(bd.buffer.asUint8List(), flush: true);
    return tempFile;
  }
openFileFromAsset().then((file){OpenFile.open(file.path);});
```

Also update your pubspec.yaml file:

```html
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/files/samplefile.docx
```